# PHP - Can't execute c++ binary files?

Tags: php, c++, binary, exec, execute

I am trying to execute c++ binary files, that i have generated using cmake and make command, from PHP. If i try to execute the same command from terminal everything works perfect but from php nothing seems to be happening. I checked the safe_mode, its off. I have given all executable permissions using chmod. I have tried putting stuff in same folder, different folder. In fact i have tried every possible solution i can think of but still i'm not able to execute these binary. Any idea why i'm not able to do so?

Any help would be really really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Procedure i used :-

```
if($dir !== FALSE) {
    $command = "./segmentation.sh $dir->dirname >> $dir->dirname/log"; 
    $output = $this->terminal($command);
    echo $output['output'];
}
```

terminal function

```
public function terminal($command)
{
    if(function_exists('system'))
    {
        ob_start();
        system($command , $return_var);
        $output = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
    }
    else if(function_exists('passthru'))
    {
        ob_start();
        passthru($command , $return_var);
        $output = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
    }
    else if(function_exists('exec'))
    {
        exec($command , $output , $return_var);
        $output = implode("n" , $output);
    }
    else if(function_exists('shell_exec'))
    {
        $output = shell_exec($command) ;
    }
    else
    {
        $output = 'Command execution not possible on this system';
        $return_var = 1;
    }
    return array('output' => $output , 'status' => $return_var);
}
```

And my shell script has a normal call to binary like

```
/path/to/folder/binary_file $args
```

I tried echo, ls, mkdir cmd from my shell script and it worked perfect only these binaries are not getting executed.

Comment: bet its a user permission issue

Comment: Can you provide some code to how you are attempting to execute the c++ binary?

Also, who is the owner of the c++ binary? Needs to be the same as the user you're running the webserver as.

Comment: @neutron i have posted a piece of code. take a look.

Comment: @Dagon i have given all the executable permission to my shell script and binary files.

Comment: files, but what about users

Comment: Yeah done that as well. All the user have all the permission. :(

Comment: The next thing to check is path settings.  Have you tried an absolute path to your executable in your `$command`?

Comment: I posted the answer guys. It was idiot MAMP. Thanks everyone who tried to help me. I really appreciate your efforts guys.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your working directory may be different than you think it is.

Try this:

```
$path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) );

$cmd = $path . $command;
```

and try executing that command (assuming the c++ file is in the same directory as the php file you are running.

Answer (score 0):

It was MAMP that causing the issue.

If you are using MAMP like me then you have to perform one more thing.

Go to Menu->Go to Folder->Write "/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/" in Text box->Press enter

Find file called  "envvars" and comment the following lines using # :-

DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

Everything should work fine now.

[Credit goes to this blog - Author Jonathon Hill](http://jonathonhill.net/2012-06-22/cannot-run-a-binary-executable-from-php-and-mamp/)

Comment: You should recreate the contents of that post here.  With credit, of course.